# speed up through parallel.for

Tags: c#, sql-server, task-parallel-library

need to download a lot of data (daily) from oracle, then delete data on sql server (in case of reruns) and then paste data into sql server with sqlbulk copy. Non parallel version :

```
     for (int i = 0; i < curves.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
                //download data from oracle
                var data = GetCurve(connectString, impdate, curves.Rows[i]);
                //delete old data in sql server
                DeleteSQL(DateTime.Now, curves.Rows[i]);
                //write to sql server with sqlbulk.copy
                writeCurve(data, "dbo.t_Curves");
}
```

I wanted to speed this up using parallel for, but obviously these steps are dependent on each other. This is what I came up with (I have never used task factory before):

```
Parallel.For(0, curves.Rows.Count, i =>
        {
                var taskLoad = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetCurve(connectString, impdate, curves.Rows[i]));
                var taskDelete = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DeleteSQL(impdate, curves.Rows[i]));
                taskDelete.Wait();
                taskLoad.Wait();
                var taskWrite = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => writeCurve(taskLoad.Result, "dbo.t_Curves"));
  });
```

This roughly halves the time. Is halving time what I can expect? Is this the correct use of threading? Is this all I can do? Can I include any further speed ups?

**UPDATE**

Just for info, Curves is a datatable with definitions and I m not writing or reading anything line by line.

Or should I write this like this:

```
 Parallel.For(0, curves.Rows.Count, i =>
        {
                var taskLoad = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetCurve(connectString, impdate, curves.Rows[i]));
                var taskDelete = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DeleteSQL(impdate, curves.Rows[i]));
                var res1 = await taskDelete;
                var res2 = await taskLoad;
                writeCurve(res2, "dbo.t_Curves");
  });
```

Comment: @Silvermind: No, I would like it to be as fast as possible and I dont really know whether I have used taks factory correctly, I have never used it before (I guess numbers are only indicative to show speed up, maybe halving time is all I can expect?)

Comment: I don't think you need to spin up a task for the writing part since you just want it to run after the load and delete tasks are done.

Comment: @juharr: good point, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Is this the correct use of threading?**

*A: Yes, you are doing the expensive work on 2 separate tasks, and then and then waiting for them to complete before carrying on.* Definitely +1 to @jugarr for pointing out that you don't need another task for the final bit of work

**Q: Is this All You Can Do?**

*Probably no, from the sound of what you are doing you are

- Getting a Single Row (from Oracle)
- Deleting a Single Row (in case it already exists) in MSSQL
- Adding the Single row back to MSSQL

Some recommendations:

- Batch it up, don't work with a single row at a time.
- Profile what the slowest part is, is it retrieving the data, deleting it, or inserting? It could be that:

  - working with single rows, the overhead of starting a
    new connection could be massive. It could be that
  - Missing indexes when trying to retrieve the data
  - Missing indexes when trying to delete the data because of Referential Integrity

What throughput rate are you getting? How many MB/s? Is each curve 1MB or 1GB?

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, I m loading entire curve from oracle at once (up to 25000 rows) to datatable and then use sql bulk copy for the insert. The rows in my code refer to a row of a datatable with definitions for the queries

Comment: does task.result include a task.wait() making the taskLoad.Wait() redundant?